# How do Compile and Module work in a code?

Tags: functions, function-construction, compile

I am trying to understand the following code in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59275/664) regarding Möbius transformation:

```
(* Projection from the sphere to the plane *)
stereo = Compile[{{xyz, _Real, 1}, {XYZ, _Real, 1}}, Module[{
     r = Sqrt[(xyz[[1]] - XYZ[[1]])^2 + (xyz[[2]] - XYZ[[2]])^2],
     theta = ArcTan[(xyz[[1]] - XYZ[[1]]), (xyz[[2]] - XYZ[[2]])]},
    {(r (1 + xyz[[3]]))/(1 - XYZ[[3]] + xyz[[3]]) Cos[theta + Pi] + xyz[[1]],
     (r (1 + xyz[[3]]))/(1 - XYZ[[3]] + xyz[[3]]) Sin[theta + Pi] + xyz[[2]], 0}]];
```

I have read the documents for the functions [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) and [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html), but still cannot figure out how the code works.

Could anyone elaborate the following?

- What does `{xyz,_Real,1}` do and what does `xyz[[1]]` mean?

  [Added:] In the document for `Compile`, it is said that

  > `Compile[{{x1,t1,n1},…},expr]` assumes that `xi` is a rank `ni` array of        objects, each of a type that matches `ti`.

  But what is `1` in `{xyz,_Real,1}`? If it means rank 1, then why later it is written that `xyz[[1]]`, `xyz[[2]]`, `xyz[[3]]`, which suggests that `xyz` is an array?
- How do `Compile` and `Module` work together to give the definition of a function?
- What is the formula for the function that this code is really defining? What is the input and what it is the output?

Comment: [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [Compile](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) will pretty quickly help to explain your first bulleted question.

Comment: Be sure to *always* read under "Details and Options" on documentation pages. You can select `[[` and press F1 (or Command-Shift-F) to see what it is (it's array indexing).  The formula is exactly as written there, just substitute in `r` and `theta` from the first part of the `Module`.  `xyz` in this case is a three-element real array representing a 3D vector with x, y, z components.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you for your comment. I'm slowly learning things and I might come back later with my own answer. I would like to leave the question undeleted (if it is not a very stupid trivial one `:-)`).

Comment: Rank 1 is an array, you're thinking about rank 0 which is a point. Rank 2 is a matrix, etc. `Module` does the same thing inside `Compile` as it does outside `Compile`.

Comment: @C.E.: the rank is indeed confusing at first. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As the document says,

  > `Compile[{{x1,t1,n1},…},expr]` assumes that `xi` is a rank `ni` array of        objects, each of a type that matches `ti`.

  Hence, `{xyz,_Real,1}` means `xyz` is a rank 1 array of "real numbers". Since `xyz` is a vector, `xyz[[1]]` means the first component of `xyz`. Therefore, if `xyz={2,4,3}`, then `xyz[[1]]=2`.
- The `expr` in `Compile[{{x1,t1,n1},…},expr]` is given by the block of `Module`, a simple example of which for seeing how it works could be

  ```
  f=Module[{r=x,theta=y},{r,theta,r+theta}];
  ```
- Here is how the function really works. Given $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the output of the function is 
  $$
  \bigg(\frac{r(1+x_3)}{1+x_3-y_3}\cos(\theta+\pi)+x_1,
  \frac{r(1+x_3)}{1+x_3-y_3}\sin(\theta+\pi)+x_2,0\bigg)
  $$
  where
  $$
  r:=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2},\quad
  \theta:=\arctan\frac{x_2-y_2}{x_1-y_1}.
  $$

  The coordinate of the center of the sphere $S$ is given by $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and the radius of the sphere is $1$. This makes sense since the output of the function is of the form $(R\cos\psi+x_1,R\sin\psi+x_2,0)$, which implies that $x_1,x_2$ are the first two coordinates of the center of the sphere.

  On the other hand, $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is the coordinate of a point on the sphere. The output of the function gives the coordinate of the "sterographic projection" of $y$ (the intersection of the line (which goes through $y$ and the north pole of the sphere) with the complex plane). When $x=(0,0,0),$ the function coincides with [the one defined in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Definition).

---

One needs to be careful with the definition $\theta$ since in Mathematica, `ArcTan[x,y]` is different from the function $\arctan\frac{y}{x}$. For instance one has in Mathematica `ArcTan[1,1]`=$\frac{\pi}{4}$ and `ArcTan[-1,-1]`=$\frac{-3\pi}{4}$. This is why $\theta+\pi$ instead of $\theta$ is used in the output of the function. For the sake of a *function*, one could define $\theta$ as the angle of the vector $(y_1-x_1,y_2-x_2,0)$ with the $X_1$-axis and replace $\theta+\pi$ with $\theta$ in the output of the function.

In the code, one could replace `theta = ArcTan[(xyz[[1]] - XYZ[[1]]), (xyz[[2]] - XYZ[[2]])]` with `theta = ArcTan[(XYZ[[1]] - xyz[[1]]), (XYZ[[2]] - xyz[[2]])]` and `theta + Pi` in the `Cos` and `Sin` functions with `theta`.

Having not checked it though, I think one can simply replace `Cos[theta+Pi]` with `XYZ[[1]]-xyz[[1]]` and `Sin[theta+Pi]` with `XYZ[[2]]-xyz[[2]]` so that one does not need to introduce the variable `theta` at all.